# dotMemory snapshot causes wpf to crash

Tags: c#, wpf, memory

I'm using dotMemory to investigate a memory leak in my WPF application. However, when I try to take a snapshot, the application crashes, and it is not apparent why.

Has anyone else have a similar experience and a reason for why this might happen?

Comment: Does your application load any COM interop DLLs?

Comment: It doesn't from what I can tell

Comment: Any exception thrown? Anything related to your application or to dotMemory in Windows Event Viewer?

Comment: They crash dump shows the exception "The thread tried to read from or write to a virtual address for which it does not have the appropriate access."

Comment: Sounds like one for the JetBrains forums, or their technical support. I would start methodically disabling parts of the application, running dotMemory each time. You should be able to track down the general area of the leak that way. Have you tried another memory profiler? The built-in VS one, or ANTS, or something?

Comment: I have not tried another one. I'll see what ANTS can do...

Comment: Cool. Don't forget you can answer your own question if the problem's solution turns out to be something worth sharing.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please submit your request to our support? I can't ask you for logs or debug without it. Thank you very much!

http://dotnettools-support.jetbrains.com/anonymous_requests/new

---

Mikhail Pilin - Profiling Core Architect, Senior Software Developer in JetBrains s.r.o.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar experience. Something wrong with .NET. I would try reinstalling the framework and see what happens.